# compiling nginx config with modules fails

Tags: ubuntu, nginx, config

Hello I am attempting to compile the config for nginx on an ubuntu digital ocean droplet and am following this tutorial

https://dev.to/samuyi/how-to-setup-nginx-for-hls-video-streaming-on-centos-7-3jb8

However when I attempt to run this bit of the tutorial in my console seen below.

```
./configure  --add-module=../nginx-rtmp-module \
--sbin-path=/usr/sbin/nginx \ 
--lock-path=/var/run/nginx.lock \
--conf-path=/etc/nginx/nginx.conf \
--pid-path=/run/nginx.pid \   
--with-pcre=../pcre-8.42 \    
--with-zlib=../zlib-1.2.11 \  
--with-openssl=../openssl-1.0.2q \
--error-log-path=/var/log/nginx/error.log \
--http-log-path=/var/log/nginx/access.log \
--user=nginx \                 
--group=nginx \                
--with-http_auth_request_module \
--with-http_degradation_module \
--with-http_geoip_module \     
--with-http_gunzip_module \    
--with-http_gzip_static_module \
--with-http_image_filter_module \
--with-http_mp4_module \
--with-http_perl_module \
--with-http_realip_module \
--with-http_secure_link_module \
--with-http_slice_module \
--with-http_ssl_module  \
--with-http_stub_status_module \
--with-http_v2_module \
--with-stream_ssl_module \
--with-stream \
--with-threads \
--prefix=/etc/nginx
```

I am met with this error and am unable to compile I am not sure whats going on or if maybe I am pasting it in wrong any advice would be greatly appreciated.

```
root@ubuntu-s-1vcpu-1gb-sfo2-01:~/nginx-1.15.9# ./configure  --add-module=../nginx-rtmp-module \
> --sbin-path=/usr/sbin/nginx \
--error-log-path=/var/log/nginx/error.log \
--http-log-path=/var/log/nginx/access.log \
--user=nginx \
--group=nginx \
--with-http_auth_request_module \
--with-http_degradation_module \
--with-http_geoip_module \
--with-http_gunzip_module \
--with-http_gzip_static_module \
--with-http_image_filter_module \
--with-http_mp4_module \
--with-http_perl_module \
--with-http_realip_module \
--with-http_secure_link_module \
--with-http_slice_module \
--with-http_ssl_module  \
--with-http_stub_status_module \
--with-http_v2_module \
--with-stream_ssl_module \
--with-stream \
--with-threads \
--prefix=/etc/nginx./configure: error: invalid option " "
root@ubuntu-s-1vcpu-1gb-sfo2-01:~/nginx-1.15.9# --lock-path=/var/run/nginx.lock \
> --conf-path=/etc/nginx/nginx.conf \
> --pid-path=/run/nginx.pid \
-bash: --lock-path=/var/run/nginx.lock: No such file or directory
root@ubuntu-s-1vcpu-1gb-sfo2-01:~/nginx-1.15.9# --with-pcre=../pcre-8.42 \
-bash: --with-pcre=../pcre-8.42: No such file or directory
root@ubuntu-s-1vcpu-1gb-sfo2-01:~/nginx-1.15.9# --with-zlib=../zlib-1.2.11 \
-bash: --with-zlib=../zlib-1.2.11: No such file or directory
root@ubuntu-s-1vcpu-1gb-sfo2-01:~/nginx-1.15.9# --with-openssl=../openssl-1.0.2q \
> --error-log-path=/var/log/nginx/error.log \
> --http-log-path=/var/log/nginx/access.log \
> --user=nginx \
-bash: --with-openssl=../openssl-1.0.2q: No such file or directory
root@ubuntu-s-1vcpu-1gb-sfo2-01:~/nginx-1.15.9# --group=nginx \
--group=nginx: command not found
root@ubuntu-s-1vcpu-1gb-sfo2-01:~/nginx-1.15.9# --with-http_auth_request_module \
> --with-http_degradation_module \
> --with-http_geoip_module \
--with-http_auth_request_module: command not found
root@ubuntu-s-1vcpu-1gb-sfo2-01:~/nginx-1.15.9# --with-http_gunzip_module \
--with-http_gunzip_module: command not found
root@ubuntu-s-1vcpu-1gb-sfo2-01:~/nginx-1.15.9# --with-http_gzip_static_module \
> --with-http_image_filter_module \
> --with-http_mp4_module \
> --with-http_perl_module \
> --with-http_realip_module \
> --with-http_secure_link_module \
> --with-http_slice_module \
> --with-http_ssl_module  \
> --with-http_stub_status_module \
> --with-http_v2_module \
> --with-stream_ssl_module \
> --with-stream \
> --with-threads \
> --prefix=/etc/nginx
```

Thank you for your time :)

Answer (score 3):

never mind I figured it out there were extra spaces behind the / of every module I removed them and it worked :)

Answer (score 0):

You should remove all **spaces symbol** behind the `/`, if there is any space symbol, command errors will occur.